# Do you have to setup roles in spring security

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security, annotations

I'm creating a simple web app that has a user login.  I'm trying to use Spring Security to manage authorization and I want to know if it is possible to use SS without setting up roles.  There is no admin or special permissions, a user is either logged in or they aren't.

All tutorials I found make you setup a roles table and userroles join table in your database and the same entities in your files.  This seems like overkill for what I want.  Is it possible to just use SS to check a username and password and log the user in if they match what is in the database without doing all the role stuff?

Comment: you need to understand the difference between authentication and authorization

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isAuthenticated()`. See more in Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you have to setup roles in spring security.

And in my opinion, the role is for different page access, like you have admin and normal user, and you want to let the different roles go to different pages.

You can use authorities="ROLE_USER" everywhere, if you just have a small application.

Hope this can help you.